# Improving use of QGIS GDAL Contour Polygon function

Tags: qgis, contour, polygon-creation, gdal-contour

I'm trying to extract vector contour polygons from a DEM, but it always takes a long time. While the Line function can finish the DEM in an hour at most, with the same parameters, the Polygon function can go 9 hours and only go up 15%. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The method that's working for me is using the contour polygon `-fl` to extract the polygons along each interval.